# Recursive binary search in an int array using only 1 parameter

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, binary-search

How can i implement a recursive binary search in an int array using only 1 parameter in java ?
it tried but my code doesn't work. I implemented a class which its instances are objects having arrays and a count variable to detect how many elements are their in the array. any idea how can i implement the recursive binary search using only 1 parameter ?

```
public class LinearSortedArray {
    int count;
    int[] a;

    public LinearSortedArray() {
        count = 0;
    }

    public LinearSortedArray(int size) {
        count = 0;
        a = new int[size];
    }

    public static int[] copyingMethod(int startPoint, int endPoint,
            LinearSortedArray arrayObj) {
        int[] copyingArray = new int[endPoint - startPoint];
        int j = startPoint;
        for (int i = 0; i < copyingArray.length; i++) {
            copyingArray[i] = arrayObj.a[j];
            j++;
        }
        return copyingArray;
    }

    public int binarySearchRec(int x) {
        if (count == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        int pivot = count / 2;
        LinearSortedArray newArrayObj;
        if (x > a[pivot]) {
            newArrayObj = new LinearSortedArray(count - pivot);
            newArrayObj.count = newArrayObj.a.length;
            newArrayObj.a = copyingMethod(pivot, count, this);

            for (int i = 0; i < newArrayObj.a.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(newArrayObj.a[i]);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            return pivot + newArrayObj.binarySearchRec(x);
        } else if (x < a[pivot]) {
            newArrayObj = new LinearSortedArray(pivot);
            newArrayObj.count = newArrayObj.a.length;
            newArrayObj.a = copyingMethod(0, pivot, this);
            for (int i = 0; i < newArrayObj.a.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(newArrayObj.a[i]);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            return newArrayObj.binarySearchRec(x);
        } else {
            return pivot;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.: The arrays are already sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary search really requires a *range* and a *target value* -- so if you're only passing one parameter, this has to be the *target* and *this* must encapsulate the array & range.

```
public class ArraySegment {
    protected int[] array;
    protected int boundLo;
    protected int boundHi;

    public class ArraySegment (int[] array) {
        // entire array.
        this( array, 0, array.length);
    }
    public class ArraySegment (int[] array, int lo, int hi) {
        this.array = array;
        this.boundLo = lo;
        this.boundHi = hi;
    }

    public int binarySearch (int target) {
        if (boundHi <= boundLo) {
            return -1;         // Empty;  not found.
        }

        int pivot = (boundLo + boundHi) / 2;
        int pivotEl = array[ pivot];
        if (target == pivotEl) {
            return pivot;      // Found!
        }
        if (target < pivotEl) {
            // recurse Left of pivot.
            ArraySegment sub = new ArraySegment( array, boundLo, pivot);
            return sub.binarySearch( target);
        } else {
            // recurse Right of pivot.
            ArraySegment sub = new ArraySegment( array, pivot, boundHi);
            return sub.binarySearch( target);
        }
    }
}
```

It's a little bit questionable what kind of result you should return -- there isn't a good answer with the question posed like this, as an "integer index" kinda defeats the purpose of the ArraySegment/ range wrapper, and returning an ArraySegment containing only the found value is also fairly useless.

PS: You really shouldn't be copying the array or it's contents, just passing round references to ranges on that array. Like `java.lang.String` is a range on a character array.

Answer (score 0):

You could contrive a single-parameter by using the [Value Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object), where you pass one "wrapper" object, but the object has many fields.

For example:

```
class SearchParams {
    int target;
    int start;
    int end;  
    SearchParams(t, s, e) {
        target = t;
        start = s;
        end = e'
    }
}

int search(SearchParams params) {
    // some impl
    return search(new SearchParams(params.target, a, b));
}
```

Technically, this is one parameter. Although it may not be in the spirit of the rules.